# Servlet should have a mapping and cannot resolve Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, web.xml

When I open my project, I get the error:

> Servlet should have a mapping

and the other error:

> Cannot resolve Servlet

[image]

But in the below code you can see every servlet have its mapping:

In my `web.xml`, I have 8 servlet, and every servlet has its corresponding mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sam.servlet.loginservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>changeservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sam.servlet.changeservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Searchservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sam.servlet.Searchservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>borrowservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sam.servlet.borrowservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>mealselectservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sam.servlet.mealselectservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>mealaddservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sam.servlet.mealaddservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>mealdeletedservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sam.servlet.mealdeletedservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>mealupdateservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sam.servlet.mealupdateservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<!-- mapping -->

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>changeservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/changeservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Searchservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Searchservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>borrowservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/borrowservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mealselectservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mealselectservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mealaddservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mealaddservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mealdeletedservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mealdeletedservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mealupdateservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mealupdateservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Looks ok, which IDE are you using?

Comment: @ammoQ, I use IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? Does https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151597#comment=27-1326420 help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I use ItelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3, and I click your link get `You have no permissions to view this page`.

Comment: Try again to open that link. See the comment for the workaround or update to the latest version.

Comment: @CrazyCoder this solved my issue, thank you, could I put it as the answer of the question here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a known issue that is already fixed in the current IntelliJ IDEA version. For the older versions [there is a workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151597#comment=27-1326420):

> please open Project Structure | Modules | Web Facet and add your `web.xml` as Deployment Descriptor.

Comment: Thank you. I use Intellij IDEA 2020.2 and the issue still persists. This suggestion saved my time as I have already wasted enough on this!

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, please open **Project Structure -> Modules -> Web Facet** and add your `web.xml` as Deployment Descriptor.

[see image detail here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KIli.png)